# What is the maximum value of $a + b + c$, given $ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{5}$

Tags: number-theory

What is the maximum value of $a + b + c$, where $a, b, c\in \mathbb{Z}$, and 
$$
\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{5}
$$

Note: I could solve the question if the question asks "minimum" instead of "maximum". The answer would be calculated as 45 with arithmetic mean - harmonic mean inequality, where all $a, b, c$ are equal to 15, and that would be the minimum value of $a+b+c$. However, the question asks for the maximum value. I could find some other valid solutions, such as $a=6$, $b=31$, $c=930$, giving the sum equal to 967. I cannot prove whether any larger integer solutions exist or not.

Comment: are the variables $a,b,c$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: Is it clear that there is a maximum?  If you drop the integrality, then there clearly is not.

Comment: @lulu Exactly this makes the problem interesting. :)

Comment: Assuming all three are positive, it's a finite problem.  Order so that $a≤b≤c$.  Remark that $6≤a≤15$.  For fixed $a$ look at $\frac 15-\frac 1a$.  That is meant to be $\frac 1b+\frac 1c$ and again there are only finitely many things $b$ might be.

Comment: Note:  that argument works even if the variables might be negative. Now order them as $|a|≤|b|≤|c|$.   You lose the inequality $6≤|a|$ but you still have $|a|≤15$ which is the important one.

Comment: @lulu I think you should post it as an answer

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti  I figure someone will come up with a less mechanical approach.  For what it's worth, the OP already has the best value if you assume positivity (and trust my hastily written program).  Second best is $(7,18,630)$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much. Now I know that the solution is finite and there is at least a mechanical way to solve the problem.

Comment: No problem.  I believe your answer is optimal even if the variables can be negative (that doesn't seem to get you big values for $a+b+c$).   Still, I wrote the relevant code very rapidly and could easily have made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking any insight, what follows is a purely mechanical approach.  We'll show that there are only finitely many possibilities for $a,b,c$.  We will not assume that they are all positive.

Taking any solution, sort it so that $|a|≤|b|≤|c|$.   We remark that $$\frac 15=\big \vert \frac 1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c\big \vert≤ \frac 1{|a|}+\frac 1{|b|}+\frac 1{|c|}≤\frac 3{|a|}\implies |a|≤15$$

Thus there are only finitely many possible values for $a$.

Fix a choice of $a$.  Now we have $\frac 1b+\frac 1c=\frac 15-\frac 1a$  and a similar argument shows that there are only finitely many choices for $b$.  As $a,b$ determine $c$ we are done.

Note:  I did the search via computer and it appears that the OP has the optimal solution in $(6,31,930)$.  However I strongly advise checking this more carefully than I have done.